# List Index out of range explanation

Tags: python, list

[image]

My code is

```
def is_array_a_subsequence_of_sequence(array, sequence):
    x_array = 0
    x_sequence = 0
    while len(array) >= len(sequence) and len(sequence) > 0:
        if array[x_array] == sequence[x_sequence]:
            x_array += 1
            x_sequence += 1
        if array[x_array] != sequence[x_sequence]:
            x_array += 1
    if len(array) and len(sequence) == 0:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)

is_array_a_subsequence_of_sequence([0,1,2,4],[0,4])
```

but it keeps returning

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\andre\PycharmProjects\fun\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    is_array_a_subsequence_of_sequence([0,1,2,4],[0,4])
  File "C:\Users\andre\PycharmProjects\fun\main.py", line 8, in is_array_a_subsequence_of_sequence
    if array[x_array] != sequence[x_sequence]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand how the index can be out of range

Comment: To debug a tiny program just add `print`-s to display involved variables.

Comment: @VPfB: no! Don't use print for debugging. This has already led to severe bugs.

Comment: @ThomasWeller What other tool can a novice use without spending hours to learn it first?

Comment: @VPfB: well, I think it's necessary to learn. We teach debugging in apprenticeships withing the first 4 hours of learning.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, in your IDE you have a button with a little bug on it:

[image: Bug button]

Use that one to debug your application, i.e. whenever it has a bug.

Whenever an exception occurs, it will stop and you can look at all variables:

[image: Variables]

As you can see, `x_array` is 4, but the array does not have 5 elements (0 though 4).

You can also put a breakpoint with a condition, like so:

[image: Breakpoint condition]

and from there step through your code line by line

[image: Stepping]

Thus you can see variables change and find out when the critical increment happens.

**Learn how to debug. You'll need it all your programmers life long.**

Don't use `print` statements. Maybe that's how debugging worked in the 1980s, not nowadays.

Comment: +1 for `Learn how to debug. You'll need it all your programmers life long.Don't use print statements. Maybe that's how debugging worked in the 1980s, not nowadays.`I spent almost 1 year to teach my co-workers to use debug rather than print......

Answer (score 0):

#### bugs

- You need a condition to exit `while` loop, otherwise your `x_array` and `x_sequence` will beyond the length of list.
- The logic check the result need fix.

#### code:

```
def is_array_a_subsequence_of_sequence(array,sequence):
    x_array = 0
    x_sequence = 0
    while len(array) >= len(sequence) and len(sequence) > 0 and x_array<len(array) and x_sequence<len(sequence):
        if array[x_array] == sequence[x_sequence]:
            x_array += 1
            x_sequence += 1
        else:
            x_array += 1
    print(x_array == len(array) and x_sequence == len(sequence))

is_array_a_subsequence_of_sequence([0,1,2,4],[0,4])
is_array_a_subsequence_of_sequence([0,1,2,4],[0,3])
is_array_a_subsequence_of_sequence([0,1,2,3],[0,4])
is_array_a_subsequence_of_sequence([0,1,2,3],[3,0])
is_array_a_subsequence_of_sequence([5,1,22,25,6,-1,8,10],[1,6,-1,10])
```

#### result:

```
True
False
False
False
True
```